# Error in creating a file with variable name in python

Tags: python, file

```
from datetime import datetime

time_today = datetime.now()
todayDate = time_today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
filename = "Attendance - " + todayDate
with open(f'{filename}.csv', 'w') as fp:
    fp.writelines(f'Name,Date,Time')
```

This is my code for creating a new file with a variable file name.
When i use just `filename="hello"`, it works and creates *hello.csv* but for `filename = "Attendance - " + todayDate` it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\College\Coding\SY\face-recog\file-create.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open(f'{filename}.csv', 'w') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Attendance - 29/03/2022.csv'
```

Comment: Do you see any special characters that might be interpreted differently in the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slashes in `todayDate` are getting interpreted by python as a path.

You can probably escape them or the easier method would probably be to change them to dashes instead:

`todayDate = time_today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem:

```
from datetime import datetime
    
    time_today = datetime.now()
    todayDate = time_today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    filename = "Attendance - " + str(todayDate)
    with open(f'{filename}.csv', 'w') as fp:
        fp.writelines(f'Name,Date,Time')
```